# Button type "submit" doesn't let bootstrap modal to open but type="button" doesn't fulfill my need. How to use AJAX to solve this?

Tags: django, ajax, django-forms, bootstrap-modal

I have a web page in which there is an input field. And below is an edit button. When I enter some text in the input field and press the edit button, a modal pops up and there is an input field in it also. I want to pass the text from the first input field to the input field in the modal window.

But then a problem arises. The modal window only opens when the edit button has type="button". But this type="button" doesn't submit the text input to the backend when I click the edit button. It submits the text to the backend when I use button type="submit", but then the modal doesn't open because the page reloads.

I don't know how to use AJAX, how can this be done with AJAX?

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row manage-groups">
        <div class="row g-0 login_form justify-content-center" id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate">
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="login-inpt" id="name" name="type-groups" placeholder="type in the group name">
                </div>
            
                <div class="row g-0 justify-content-center group-action">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 submit-group">
                        <div>
                            <button type="submit" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#ModalAddGroups"
                                class="button-box">Add</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 submit-group">
                        <button type="button" onclick="form_submit()" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#ModalEditGroups"
                            class="button-box">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 submit-group">
                        <button type="submit" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#ModalDeleteGroups"
                            class="button-box">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal window for Edit button -->
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalEditGroups" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content edit-modal">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Edit Group</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body grid-container">
                <input type="text" value="{{ group.group_name }}">
                {{ group.group_name }}
                {{ group }}
                <table class="edit-groupLinks">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="header">
                            <th>Links</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" value="www.google.com"></td>
                            <td><button type="button" class="delete" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button class="add-linkBTN"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-ftr">
                <button type="submit" class="button-box" id="footer-btn">Save</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Views.py file:

```
def manageGroups(request):
    form = GroupSorting()
    group = request.POST.get('type-groups', False)
    content = Groups.objects.filter(group_name__contains = group)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = GroupSorting(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            form = GroupSorting()
    
    context = {'form': form, 'group': content}
    return render(request, 'posts/manage-groups.html', context)
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want your 'edit' button to open a modal AND submit the form at same time?

Comment: If you want to use a type="submit" button without actually submitting your form, you can try adding this to your button `onclick="return false;"`

Comment: Yes, I want to use both functions from a single button. I added `onclick` argument but that only let the modal to open even if the button type is "submit"., it didn't submit the input text to the backend.

Comment: Unfortunately what you want is not possible.

Comment: You should add a separate button for submitting your form, preferably inside your modal.

Comment: can I pass the data by using javascript and keeping the button type = "button"?

Comment: If you want to submit a form without reloading the webpage, you should use [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Comment: adding a separate button inside the modal will not work for my use case, because the text I type in the input field will go to the backend, will fetch details regarding that keyword, and display in the modal.

Comment: I understand now. Then you should definitely learn to use Ajax, that's how every other website does what you want. I suggest you read the link i send earlier.

Comment: Thanks for broadening my knowledge. I highly respect that.

Comment: Hey can you help me with ajax. I know hat it does but cant understand how to do it.